# Get Value out of Option[Any] = Some(Map)

Tags: scala

I have the following data in a data type that I have not used yet Option[Any] = Some(Map:

```
Option[Any] = Some(Map(subject -> matt, predicate -> likes, object -> coffee, label -> 1_10))
```

How would I pull data out of the Map inside, for instance I want to get the label. Is there something I need to convert it to?

Comment: In Scala (as in Java) you can pretty much cast any type into something else. 99% of the time this is a code smell, in that you can still do what you want without throwing the type system out of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you knew the type of the Map (or, at least, the type of the label and it's value) you could pull it out with `asInstanceOf`:

```
val a = Option[Any](Map("a" -> "b", 1 -> 2))

a.flatMap(_.asInstanceOf[Map[Int, Int]].get(1))
// Some(2): Option[Int]
```

*Usually it's better to not have to use `asInstanceOf` but to nail down the type before hand... then you could more simply use:*

```
a.flatMap(_.get("label"))
```

Comment: This works but I would argue against bypassing the type system unless you don't have an alternative.

Comment: @marios 100% agree. The last paragraph is supposed to be: don't use asInstanceOf there's usually a better way.